# Recover particular "Folder" which is permanently deleted from desktop

Tags: finder, data-recovery, trash

I had a folder name "FruitFest" in my desktop. It's basically an iOS App project which includes a lot of files & xcode bundle in it. Today I accidentally deleted it into my trash and later on I emptied my trash. But now I badly want to get back my FruitFest folder .

Is there any way to find out that folder by some folder recovery tool/Software? Where I can get back my folder as it is? I have tied *Disk Drill* & *Stellar Phoenix Mac Data Recovery* software, but it only shows files, not any folder. If you have any suggestion please share with me.

Comment: Those utils will typically find files, not folders.  Try the recovery of what it finds.  That said, if you are trying this on an SSD, you are out of luck.

Comment: My gosh!!!! I am on SSD. :( :( :( 
Is there no way out at all?????? Please reply. :(

Comment: Perhaps you have a backup - maybe some if not all of the stuff...

Comment: I had several back up of my project mate. Today I have deleted all the other version which was in half done state. And assuming that the existing folder was my final folder. But unfortunately, the existing one is 6 months old and the final version gone to trash with other half done project. What a fool I am. :(

Comment: I should have use git. :( :( :(, my 6 months work, gone just by a single click. :(

Comment: SSDs will remove data instantaneously.   See this relevant [answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/258171/119271).  I can definitely empathize with you but use this as a learning experience as to the value of a (Time Machine) backup strategy.

Comment: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48200/recovered-deleted-files-on-mac-by-command-line