# All data easily recoverable after Disk Utility erase on 3rd party SSD?

Tags: macos, disk-utility, ssd, high-sierra, secure-erase

It's come to the time to upgrade and therefore sell my old laptop. Its a mid-2012 13″ MacBook Pro with an Intel Core i5 and 4GB RAM. Originally it came with a 500GB hard drive but I have upgraded this myself to a Crucial 480GB SSD.

After I used Time Machine to back up my data, it came time to wipe the SSD. I did some research beforehand and was told a secure erase with multiple passes is unnecessary on an SSD, and I therefore followed Apples instructions on how to prepare my laptop for sale:

1. I logged out of all iCloud services
2. Restarted and booted into (I think) recovery or internet recovery (command + R)
3. I went into Disk Utility, selected Erase, selected my Crucial SSD and erased it with the AFPS format
4. I then reinstalled macOS High Sierra and created a new user.

I wanted to test if the erase had worked, so I went on the internet and downloaded some free data recovery applications (Disk Drill and Easeus). After a few hours, to my horror, all my data came back, in the exact same path and was easily readable and recoverable. I did some more research and was told that encypting the disk would be a good way to securely erase the data (I wish I knew this beforehand!), so I turned on FileVault, let it encrypt the disk and then went through the same stages again of wiping the drive with AFPS format.

**Does FileVault encypt data that has already been deleted?** I ran the same recovery software for a second time, which again, found all my old files in the same paths, however this time I couldn't preview or open them once recovered. Is this FileVault at work or has something else gone wrong that could easily be fixed by someone wanting to access my files?

**What can I do?** It's alarming me that the names of all my files are still easily found in the same directories with free software found at the top of a google search, but I don't mind too much if they cant be opened. **Is there something else I should be doing to permanently erase this free space? Is my data essentially safe?**

Comment: When you upgraded your HDD to an SSD, did you enable TRIM?  See this post:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/258171/119271

Comment: Hi allan, no I can't remember doing this to be honest. I read about it but didnt do any terminal commands etc.

Comment: TRIM is the ATA command subset for SSDs  that mark deleted space as unused and if a read command comes in, it returns either zeros or jibberish.  If it wasn't enabled, it "acts" like a regular drive meaning  data is recoverable.  I suspect this is the case.  In the link I provided, it gives you instructions to wipe the drive.  Enable TRIM then do a single pass of zeros.  Your data will be gone

Comment: Will my SSD definitely support TRIM, and if I enable it could I fill the SSD with 480gb or so worth of files and then delete them all? would this effectively be the same as writing zeroes? Or should I just follow those instructions and write zeroes?

Comment: Your SSD will support TRIM.  Filling it with 480 GB  or filling with zeros is the same thing; just the zeros are easier. It’s like comparing the weight difference between a ton of lead or a ton of feathers.