# Disk Utility - Secure Erase is not working in terminal

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, disk-utility, ssd

I'm trying to securely erase my SSD by using `diskutil` in terminal in the recovery mode (restart --> hold down command+R --> terminal)

I first use `diskutil list` to find the disk name, which is disk0:
[image]

Then I use `diskutil secureErase 0 disk0` to erase the disk:
[image]

However, the error "Couldn't open disk" happened. I tried to go to the UI version of Disk Utility, unmount the disk and erase again, but the same problem happens.

Comment: What Mac, what drive type, what OS? Secure erase should be avoided for for SSDs

Comment: It is a macbook air. For OS, actually before using the diskutil in terminal, I erased the disk in the UI version of Disk Utility, so there is no OS now. But now I need secure erase and that's why I'm trying to do it in terminal. I just want to secure erase by a single pass of 0, which should be fine for SSD

Comment: See this answer - especially the 2nd half - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/258171/85275

Comment: You may have already figured this out, but the secure erase option isn't available for Solid State Drives (SSD) - basically because it's not needed and, in fact, can shorten the life of the SSD.