# How to undelete files removed with rm -rf on an APFS SSD disk?

Tags: apfs, macos

Is there any way to restore files removed with `rm -rf` on an APFS formatted SSD?

Comment: It’s unlikely el to be successful, but you can try Disk Drill or Disk Warrior recovery tools

Comment: Restore from a Time Machine backup. (Assuming you have one.)

Comment: Do you have APFS snapshots or TimeMachine ever set up once? (Or are you asking us to answer that triage question as an answer?)

Comment: You can try running `tmutil listlocalsnapshots /` to see if you have any local APFS snapshots.  Any consumption of disk space could cause the system to be starved for disk space, and start deleting old snapsshots, so stop what you're mmediately stop using your computer, and reboot into recovery mode to restore it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### No. It's very unlikely you're going to recover anything.

The reason being is that when you delete something from an SSD, the *way* it's deleted makes it virtually impossible to recover.  Basically, when you delete something, it tells the drive to mark the sectors as deleted just like in a traditional hard drive.  However, when subsequently asked to read back the data, the drive will respond back with either zeros or garbage.

- [How to get the "securely erase" function of Disk Utility on El Capitan & Sierra](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/258170/119271)
- [Can the data on an MacBook Pro SSD be recovered after formatting using Disk Utility](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/269863/119271)

Note:  It's not *impossible* that you’re unable to recover any data; you will need to send it to a lab or to the manufacturer who can get around the mechanisms that secures the data.  However, this is usually very cost prohibitive unless it's for forensics and provided that the sector hasn't been overwritten already.  Unlike magnetic media, it only takes a single write to send the preexisting data into oblivion.

Comment: Also, SSD+APFS means you have snapshots and ghost data due to copy on write. So if you can get a snapshot, even when TimeMachine isn’t expected to be in play, this makes recovery trivial. But it also makes trolling free space much less likely to succeed (and more labor intensive) versus magnetic storage and HFS.

Comment: Are the snapshots created automatically? Is there a way to view snapshots? Ie from command line?

Comment: *just like in a traditional hard drive* - no, TRIM commands on an SSD have no equivalent on a traditional HD.  It's an optional additional thing that a filesystem can do after the normal process of updating its metadata (on other blocks of the disk) to remove any references to this block as being in-use and add it to the FS's free list.  (The filesystem has to keep track of its own in-use / free blocks separately from the SSD firmware block remapping layer.  Filesystems work even inside disk image files with no underlying disk hardware, and magnetic HDDs don't support TRIM.)

Comment: But yes, if your FS issues a TRIM command on the fly for the sectors of a file, your data is gone.  It sounds like you're saying MacOS's APFS driver does that (by default?).  (Linux can do online TRIM, or you can set up a `fstrim` cron job to TRIM all the free space once a week or something.)

Comment: It only takes a single write to send preexisting data into oblivion on modern spinning hard drives, too (which use [PMR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpendicular_recording)). This has been true for almost 15 years.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to easily recover the files deleted by rm. You will ned a 3rd part app to do so. There is an app called [Stellar](https://www.stellarinfo.com/gdc/file-recovery-mac.php?gclid=Cj0KCQjwyur0BRDcARIsAEt86IBdrtV--a02umMocO3EcrP1gxtEVk4lNBTLVYjPZ7R4u1bDHP_gavcaAv6bEALw_wcB), [EaseUS](https://www.easeus.com/landing/mac-deleted-file-recovery.htm?gclid=Cj0KCQjwyur0BRDcARIsAEt86IDTkb96qIbmKwPD41kMmUcbFSN5cOHI_xlbX8INZ05M4GxOPPcVGxIaAqWnEALw_wcB&utm_expid=.AIdhas4STuq6MNiHTZqIBQ.0&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F), or [Disk Drill](https://www.cleverfiles.com/?gclid=Cj0KCQjwyur0BRDcARIsAEt86IBaPdt4rBd7QcAYh0cU_EtkyVj8fy9vTOZtBH8hnez92yu_AL1egO8aAlIpEALw_wcB). The first two are pricey but Disk Drill offers a level of recovery for free.

Comment: Do these work well on SSD and APFS?

Comment: Encryption is unlocked when you run disk drill. If you didn’t have the disk unlokced (where then encryption was bypassed with a key) nothing would have restored @ccpizza - sorry that it wasn’t a good recovery

Comment: @ccpizza "done more often than with old school HDDs." You shouldn't factor the availability of data recovery services into a backup strategy. They're a "nice to have" if you're in need, but in no way dependable. If anything, you should back up HDDs more, because failures are just so much more common. I would strongly recommend setting up time machine

Comment: Note to self: I payed $90 for this and it reminded me what files I deleted but failed to recover the body of any of them.