# Format disk in mac with a lot of reading and writing

Tags: catalina, ssd, disk-format, secure-erase

What I want to do is **Format my SSD disk of my Mac Book Pro (2019)**, but I want to do it in a **VERY safe way**. So that there is no trace of the deleted files and nobody can access them anymore.

That's why I think the best option is to **look for a software** that formats the disk doing a lot of **reading and writing**.

I can't find good and reliable software that does that on a Mac. Is there one?

Comment: Do you have FileVault currently enabled?

Comment: No, I don't have that enabled now.

Comment: Then what benwiggy said is as good as it gets.

Comment: You still have access to [secure erase](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/258171/119271) but it’s a waste of time.  Once you erase data from your SSD, it’s gone.

Answer (score 0):

Writing multiple zeros on an SSD does nothing to improve the secure elimination of the data, and significantly reduces the life of the drive.

If you want to make sure that your files are safe: encrypt the drive.

Comment: Okey.. But what method improve te secure elimination of the data without encrypting the drive? Because I want to delete the file for ever..

Comment: Just delete it. Without encryption, that's as good as you can get.

Comment: Oh okey. I'm going to do that, but I'm not 100% convinced. Thanks anyway

Comment: you could do a lot of reading and writing after you remove the file.  Try downloading a very big file.  Maybe several copies.  After a week or so of use get a data recovery app, one with a free trial, and see if you can recover your file. if you can't then its been written over probably.